# Div goes past its parent element

Tags: javascript, css, math, scroll, formula

I'm trying to create a custom scroller, and I'm using `translate3d` to scroll. The only problem is, when you scroll all the way to the bottom, the thumb (scroller) goes too far down. I'm using the accepted formula, but for some reason, it goes past its parent wrapper. Here's the formula:

```
scrollPosition * scrollBarThumb_height / content_height
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the thumb to fully stay in its parents view?

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
var scrollBar = document.getElementById('scrollbar');
var scrollBarThumb = scrollBar.firstElementChild

scrollBarThumb.style.height = (innerWrapper.offsetHeight * innerWrapper.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';

innerWrapper.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleScroll);
innerWrapper.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', handleScroll);

innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';

function handleScroll(e) {
  // Prevent parents from scrolling
  e.preventDefault();
  var direction = (e.detail < 0 || e.wheelDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1; // 1 = scroll down, -1 = scroll

  var start = parseInt(innerWrapper.style.transform.split(',')[1], 10);
  var scrollPosition = start + direction * 100; // Cannot use `deltaY`, because not all browsers support it.
  var scrolledToBottom = innerWrapper.scrollHeight - innerWrapper.parentElement.offsetHeight;
  scrollPosition = clamp(scrollPosition, -scrolledToBottom, 0);

  innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + scrollPosition + 'px, 0px)';
  scrollBarThumb.style.top = -(scrollPosition * scrollBarThumb.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.parentElement.offsetHeight) + 'px'
}

function clamp(val, min, max) {
  if (typeof min !== 'number') min = 0;
  if (typeof max !== 'number') max = 1;
  return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
}
```

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
#content {
  background-image: url("http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/previews/3037/30376024-beautiful-flower-portrait.jpg");
  width: 400px;
}
#scrollbar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#scrollbar_thumb {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
      sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus
      Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus
      enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar
      justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames
      ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque
      Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem
      lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie
      vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum
      vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque
      Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci
      Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla.
      Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum
      vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque
      Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scrollbar">
    <div id="scrollbar_thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a simple google search with this same title would return that duplicate ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The borders were not calculated properly into the total element's height, thus creating the problem.

Simply add `box-sizing: border-box;` to solve the issue:

```
#scrollbar_thumb {
    ...
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

working JSFiddle fork: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/9nfns6kk/

Comment: Now the problem is, it doesn't go all the way down. There's about a px between the bottom and the thumb